# UFT API - How to capture dynamic array messages keys from the API response and write in excel

Tags: hp-uft

I've come across a situation, where I need to capture the service response and store in the excel file for the different data combinations.

I've written a custom code and update the response in excel if the service response with only one message. But the messages are defined in array[] in the xml response. It's possible that the service response with multiple messsages based on the input data that I use.  This is where my test is failing.

Can anyone please help me how to handle this?

**Error Message:**
Message Couldn't Get Property: OutputEnvelope, with XPath: /*[local-name(.)='Envelope'][1]/*[local-name(.)='Body'][1]/*[local-name(.)='getRequestContextOut'][1]/*[local-name(.)='Messages'][1]/*[local-name(.)='Message'][4]/*[local-name(.)='messageKey'][1]

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this
1st : You can declare input variables and point each variable to corresponding key under the Array. when you do the data linkage , UFT will ask something like   by saying yes you UFT will create a loop for you so that however number of items under the Array , it will count the group count (like Flight/customer/orderNumber/) and loop it according to the count . at this point all you need to do is write these dynamic array keys into Excel File.

2nd : you can also do it programmatically .  here is how it works 
First declare input variable and go to the your target array link it to the variable so it hold the xml nodeList . then you can use xml Dom to access value of childNodes , It would be something Like this :
     XmlNodeList Lst  = VariableThatHoldNodeListArray;
     XmlNodeList myTargetNodes = Lst.GetElementsByTagName("YourTagHere");
     For (int i=0,i< myTargetNodes.count,i++)
           {
         this.context.UserLogger.info(myTargetNode.item(i).innerText);
     }

I recommend you go to UFT Help section , there are some valuable recourse that you will be surprised, I learned most of what I know from there , because even I know enough C# to write custom code , I did not know what class is available what is the reference for the objects , in help it will list all available objects and methods. Hope this helped. let me know if you need any more question